# CSS Selector nth-child producing odd results

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am experience some strange issues while using the CSS `nth-child` selector.

**I have the following HTML:**

```
<div class="block feature-callout-c" id="overview">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="span twelve">

            <span class="intro">ABCD</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row number">
        <div class="span two">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="span two data-stat">
            <i class="text">500M</i>
            <p><span class="faux-tip">Tweets</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span two data-stat">
            <i class="text">20M+</i>
            <p><span class="faux-tip">Blog Posts</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span two data-stat">
            <i class="text">200M</i>
            <p><span class="faux-tip">bitly Clicks</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span two data-stat">
            <i class="text">85M</i>
            <p><span class="faux-tip">Tumblr Posts</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span two">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The following CSS doesn't select anything:**

```
DIV.block.feature-callout-c#overview:nth-child(2) 
    DIV.row.number:nth-child(2) 
        DIV.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(1) 
            I.text
```

**Whereas this one does:**

```
DIV.block.feature-callout-c#overview:nth-child(2) 
    DIV.row.number:nth-child(2) 
        DIV.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(2) 
            P 
                SPAN.faux-tip
```

Could someone please explain what is going on here?

This is not the most **optimal** to work with CSS I have a very specific need which requires a unique selector for each element.

Comment: try adding "n" so: `nth-child(2n)`

Comment: @Adsy while that does work, it will return two elements. I want just the one (the first one).

Comment: DIV.span.two.data-stat:first-child ?

Comment: you have the first `.span.two.data-stat` as the second child of `row.number`, yet the first attempt tries to select the first child (nth-child is 1 based, not 0 based)

Comment: @PatDobson Unfortunately :first-child doesn't work either

Comment: @user2786485 Unless i'm mistaken DIV.row.number:nth-child(2) is correctly selecting DIV.span.two.data-stat in both instances. It's just the DIV.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(1) which is failing

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, `nth-child(1)` is failing because it tries to select the first child, yet the first child is `<div class="span two">&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each part of `div.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(1)` matches a part of the element it's checking against, in one big "and" check.

`:nth-child(x)` finds an element where it is the xth child of the parent.

So `div.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(1)` means "Find me all elements where the tag name is div and has the class 'contains' and has the class 'two' and has the class 'data-stat' and is the first child of its parent".

The first child of `DIV.row.number:nth-child(2)`, which you're trying to match with `DIV.span.two.data-stat:nth-child(1)`, doesn't have the class data-stat and so therefore does not match.